# Render default back button in header when specifying a custom headerLeft (react-navigation)

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Using react-navigation in a react native project, is it possible to render the default back button inside a stack navigator when specifying a custom headerLeft? Or is this only possible by explicitly returning a custom headerLeft that also contains a button that performs `navigation.goBack` on press? My current code looks like below, but I would also like the back button to be displayed when applicable (when goBack is an option).

```
export default StackNavigator(
  {
        ...,
  },
  {
    headerMode: "float",
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      headerLeft: (
        <MaterialCommunityIcons name={"menu"} style={{ color: "white" }} size={25} onPress={() => navigation.navigate("DrawerOpen")} />
      ),
      headerStyle: { backgroundColor: "#4C3E54", paddingLeft: 10, paddingRight: 10 },
      headerTitleStyle: { color: "white" }
    })
  }
)
```

Image for reference showing back button, then header after I apply custom headerLeft.

[image]

Comment: For v6, check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63692481/getting-element-type-is-invalidexpected-a-string-but-got-undefined-check-the-r/70109447#70109447

Answer (score 0):

You can set `navigationOption` for every screen differently, also you can set a default `navigationOption` for whole `StackNavigation`. In below example gestures will be disabled for every screen except `Main` screen.

**Example**

```
const ModalNavigator = StackNavigator(
 {
   Main: {
     screen: Main,
     navigationOptions: {
       gesturesEnabled: true,
     }
   },
   Login: { screen: Login },
   Profile: { screen: Profile },
 },
 {
   headerMode: 'none',
   mode: 'modal',
   navigationOptions: {
     gesturesEnabled: false,
   }
 }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

On your React Component you can override the navigation options and just choose to render a custom left button based on a navigation param, in this case if **params.editing** is false the default back button is rendered, otherwise the **Something** button is rendered:

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }: NavigationType) => {
  const params = navigation.state.params || {}

  var header = {
    title: "Home"
  }

  if (params.editing) {
    header = {
      ...header,
      headerLeft: (
          <Button onPress={params.doSomething} title="Something"/>
      )
    }
  }

  return header
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put `headerLeft: () => undefined` when you don't want to customize it.